# Selecting the max value of two different columns

Tags: sql, sql-server

[I have the following table named 'MoviesInStock'](https://i.stack.imgur.com/16uzV.png)

I would like to select to latest movies from the last month.
In this case, the result should be only the movie 'The Mummy' since he is latest one.

I was trying the next query:

```
SELECT MovieName
FROM MovieInStock
WHERE Month = (SELECT MAX(Month) FROM MovieInStock) AND
      (SELECT MovieName FROM MovieInStock WHERE Year = (SELECT MAX(Year) FROM MovieInStock))
```

But choosing the AND operator was not that smart. I was also trying to create a temporary table using `SELECT INTO #` for selecting the Max Year and then on the temp table to select the Max Month, but then it become complicated to me.

Comment: Edit your question and provide sample data and desired results.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are overcomplicating the problem.  You can use `TOP` with `ORDER BY`.

Because you say "movies":

```
select top (1) with ties mis.*
from movieinstock mis
order by year desc, month desc
```

Comment: Correct. I probably should think more simple next time.

Answer (score 0):

other solution, but better is Gordon Solution

```
with maxdt as (
select MAX(Month) MaxMonth, MAX(Year) MaxYear FROM MovieInStock
) 
SELECT top 1 MovieName
FROM MovieInStock f1 
inner join maxdt f2 on f1.Month=f2.MaxMonth and f1.Year=MaxYear
```